# Decomposition to indecomposable projective $A-$modules

Tags: projective-module, artinian

I read "Representation theory", written by Alexander Zimmermann. In the chapter 1.11, It is mentioned that:

*If $A$ be an Artinian algebra then there is a decomposition 
$$A=P_1\oplus P_2\oplus \dots\oplus P_m$$ 
into a direct sum of indecomposable projective $A-$module.*

Can someone help me, how do we can prove the statement?

Comment: Do you know that any artinian module is a finite direct sum of indecomposable submodules?

Comment: I don't know.. I think the module should be artinian and noetherian..  Could you give me some reference?

Comment: An artinian algebra is noetherian. This is a nontrivial result that you need to know, the Hopkins–Levitzki theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, any artinian module $M$ is a finite direct sum of indecomposable submodules.  To prove this, suppose it is not true and consider the collection of all submodules of $M$ that cannot be written as a finite direct sum of indecomposable submodules.  Since $M$ is artinian, this collection (which by hypothesis contains $M$ and so is nonempty) has a minimal element, say $N$.  Then $N$ is not indecomposable, so we have $N=N_1\oplus N_2$ for some proper submodules $N_1$ and $N_2$.  But by minimality of $N$, each of $N_1$ and $N_2$ is a finite direct sum of indecomposable submodules, and hence so is $N$.  This is a contradiction.

Now apply this to $A$ as a module over itself to find that $A$ is a finite direct sum $P_1\oplus \dots\oplus P_m$ of indecomposable submodules.  Since $A$ is projective and a direct summand of a projective module is projective, the $P_i$ are all projective.